# Using a regex to find a downloaded file in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, pdf

Sorry in advance if this is a dumb question; I'm still very new to node js and javascript in general. I've started using [pdf2json](https://github.com/modesty/pdf2json) and am using their pdf-to-text example to store the information of a downloaded pdf in a text file. As far as I understand it, the method takes a filepath and parses the pdf. Which would usually be fine, except that the name of the downloaded file also contains the date it was downloaded on (e.g. `HealthReport-MM-DD-YYYY.pdf`). Since it's obviously a bad idea to hard code in the path (`C:/Users/Me/Downloads/`), I was hoping it was possible to create something like `pdf2json('/Downloads/'+/^HealthReport.*/g)` in order to parse the correct pdf file regardless of when it was downloaded. I have the text file stored in a temp folder when it's created.

Example code:

```
pdf2json('/Downloads/'+/^HealthReport.*/g)
pdf2json = function(filepath) {
    let fs = require('fs'),
        PDFParser = require("pdf2json");

    let pdfParser = new PDFParser(this,1);

    pdfParser.on("pdfParser_dataError", errData => console.error(errData.parserError) );
    pdfParser.on("pdfParser_dataReady", pdfData => {
        fs.writeFile("/temp/HealthReport.content.txt", pdfParser.getRawTextContent());
    });

    pdfParser.loadPDF(filepath);
}
```

Comment: You can use [`glob`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob).

Comment: Thank you! That worked perfectly.